# Database configuration errors while deploying Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm using Rails 4.2.3

I received the classic ["sqlite not supported" error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#getting-a-sqlite-error-even-though-it-is-not-in-the-gemfile) initially, and then removed all references to `sqlite`.

Now I'm getting:

```
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): ://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname
```

My database.yml looks like this:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

I've also tried:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

production:
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 15
```

Here's what I see in the Heroku config vars:

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL

mysql://b517f4a5xxxxx:03eyyyy@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_ab11dcfzzzzzz?reconnect=true
```

Comment: Try find where the environment variable is being set, then redefine it to a valid and accurate URL (`user`, `pass` and `dbname` are probably not your actual credentials). You can run `heroku info --app myapp` to see if it has been set by Heroku.

Comment: @cobaltsoda that's a good idea... but doesn't Heroku set that URL it's self when I create the add-on? I see the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL in the Heroku settings

Comment: Oh ok, can't you just update that URL in the Heroku settings to use the correct credentials? Also you might want to try explicitly setting the protocol, which I'm assuming is `mysql://` for ClearDB

Comment: @cobaltsoda I'm pretty sure the credentials URL in Heroku are correct. I mean... if Heroku assigned me the wrong DB credentials that would be very weird. I guess I can try dropping the add-on and re-adding it. But I'm pessimistic that's the problem.

Comment: What's actually in that setting? Is it `://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname`? According to [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#configuring-your-ruby-application-to-use-cleardb) it should look different

Comment: @cobaltsoda I added the config var to the question above. That tutorial suggests I need to change the name of the config var. I'll try that.

Comment: Make sure you change that URL once you've got the whole thing fixed, if you want to keep access to your db private :)

Comment: So since that setting isn't `://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname` it looks like ActiveRecord is just using the default database url

Comment: @cobaltsoda it works when I create a duplicate config var called `DATABASE_URL` so that was it. Weird that it doesn't work when I set the ENV["..."]. If you submit an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, strange that it didn't work in the first place with `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting the solution found in the comment section:

[This tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#configuring-your-ruby-application-to-use-cleardb) suggests to copy `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` into `DATABASE_URL`, which seemed to fix the problem.